# Dropzone: Submit both form data and dropzone at once

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, dropzone.js

I know there some questions like this, but they didn't answer questions exactly.

This is what I need,

1. Upload files using `Dropzone`
2. Save form data and uploaded image paths to DB

**The problem is, How can I send both form data and dropzone files at the same time, like in the following official doc article.**

I followed this `Dropzone` official docs  [Combine normal form with Dropzone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone)

I tried this article and it worked. I could able to get both form data and files.But in this, the whole form is a `Dropzone`. I just need to make a `Dropzone` using a `div`.

Then I tried this approach,

- Upload files first and get uploaded file paths as the response
- Create hidden `input` by setting value as the file path received from a response
- Submit the form

  But the problem is if I use this approach I have to upload files first. What if a request is broken when I'm submitting the `form` ?. No data will save, but there uploaded file on the server.

I'm hoping you guys can help me out to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding more data to Dropzone.js post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472952/adding-more-data-to-dropzone-js-post)

Comment: Please have a look at the following documentation. Visit <https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/tutorials/combine-form-data-with-files>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) { 

 formData.append("fieldname1", $('field-name-1').val());  

});
```

You could probably even automate this and do an `$.each` with every input of a `#form` but the basic logic is above.

The juist of this is outlined in the [docs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) under the tab `tips`.

Comment: Thank you. This is the best solution. I didn't read much the docs. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to append form data when sending. Check the documentation and use the headers property

example

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".profile-image-upload",
    {
        paramName: "uploadfile",
        url: "/API/PeopleAPI/EditAsync",
        maxFiles: 1,
        headers: getData(),
        uploadMultiple: false,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        maxFilesize: 20,
        acceptedFiles: "image",
        dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You can only upload 1 image",
        dictDefaultMessage: "",
    });

function getData() {
        var data = {
            //person
            UserName: $('#UserName').val(),
            AspNetUserID: '@Model.AspNetUserID',
            Roles: $('#UserRoles').val(),
            FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
            Email: $('#Email').val(),
            LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
            Gender: $('#Gender').val(),
            Password: $('#Password').val(),
            //address
            AddressLine1: $('#AddressLine1').val(),
            AddressLine2: $('#AddressLine2').val(),
            Town: $('#Town').val(),
            RegionID: $('#RegionID').val(),
            RegionName: $('#RegionID :selected').text(),
            City: $('#City').val(),
            CountyID: $('#CountyID').val(),
            CountyName: $('#CountyID :selected').text(),
            PostCode: $('#PostCode').val(),
          __RequestVerificationToken: $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"').val()
        };
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible. you have to upload file first and then db record will be added/updated. once your request is submitted to server, db record will be updated in nano seconds. So no need to worry. It is same as core php.

just for the safe side your web server and db server should be same for more efficient behavior.

if still you want more security, write a crone job, that will run in the end of the day and will unlink all the files from server those doesn't exist in db record.