# send data with dropzone

Tags: javascript, upload, dropzone

I work with dropzone:

```
<form action="#" class="dropzone"  ></form>
```

In the code js, the dropzone upload images only if  a button with id=startUpload
is clicked.

```
         Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $(function() {
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
                url: "upload_hotel_image.php",
                paramName: "file",
                maxFilesize: 20,
                maxFiles: 20,
                acceptedFiles: "image/*,
                autoProcessQueue: false,

            });      
          $(document).ready(function(){  
   $('#startUpload').click(function(){   
            myDropzone.processQueue();
       });
        });
              });
```

Now, how can i add more data to send with dropzone when images  are uploaded, for exapmle,i need send description with every image uploaded.

Comment: https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending further down on that page "Dropzone will submit any hidden fields you have in your dropzone form. So this is an easy way to submit additional data. You can also use the params option." - not clear if this will also submit and normal fields or only hidden ones.  Either way, stick an input inside the dropzone form and see what happens.

Comment: Hey man you still need help with this?

Comment: yes,i still need helpfor this

Comment: Possible duplicate with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472952/adding-more-data-to-dropzone-js-post)

Answer (score 0):

//do this in your init function
this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {

```
    $("form").find("input").each(function(){
      formData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
  });
```